# Blank console page on eclipes while setting up of selenium and chromedriver but url is opening but no msg on console

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

```
package basicMethod;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Onl {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        // setting the property of chrome browser and passing chrome
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe" );
    
        //  launching chrome browser instance
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        //open url using get() method
        
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        
        
          }

    }
```

what i need to do?

how to smoothly run selenium on my laptop?